# Presentation of data - Correctness of using exponentially weighted moving average values in charts

Tags: visualization

I have a set of data that I would like to present to an audience in a chart.

The data points span several years and they each year needs to be presented as separate series.

The datapoints are daily, so a single series data looks 'busy':

[image]

My intention is to make the chart readable (overlapping multiple high-frequency series would look messy), and it is clear that I could acheive that by removing the high-frequency changes in the data.

I have attempted to group the values by downsampling from 1 day to 10 days:

[image]

Is this a valid way to solve the presentation problem? What would you do?

**EDIT:**
My question is specifically about the correctness of presenting exponentially weighted data to the audience who may not understand the implications of it.
Please consider the grouped values versus e.w. values:

[image]
[image]

A sharp drop in value becomes a much smaller dip. That looks like potential misrepresentation to me, hence my question about the conventions of presenting the data.

Trying to answer my own question, I would reason that I must choose the decay (span) parameter for the exponential weighted function, so that the result doesn't distort the 'meaningful trends' in data. Woh is to decide what is a 'meaningful trend'? My personal judgement?

Comment: Present the original data with a smoothed line to show the overall trend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205795/plotting-smooth-line-through-all-data-points

Comment: Hi @Peter, thank you for sharing. 'Smoothed line' is a very vague term, and using the weighting mentioned in the linked answer has some caveats that I have outlined in my edit. I would greatly appreciate more thoughts on this subject. Thank you again